# Use Archimedes Property to prove the existence of a rational number in an interval.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Using the Archimedes Property (where if 0M), to prove that for a

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to prove a rational number, if I'm supposed to find a p/q between (a,b), or if I'm supposed to assume some number c is rational.

If someone could help, that would be really great.

Comment: See theorem 4, on the density of the rationals ( https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m54x12/public_html/m54densitynote.pdf ) . There's also a proof that fits your purposes

Comment: Density is sufficient, I guess, to immediately conclude the existence of a rational in any interval.

Comment: Sorry, I think some of my question was cut out when I posted it. Anyways, thank you very much!